# How to add another description block outside the tabs in product detail page

Tags: attributes, themes, block, product, magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.4. I need to add a block for product detail outside from the main 'Details', 'Review' tabs. I need this block to be separated after the main description of the product. How can I do this? I have started doing this with a custom theme but no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Path and block hint from magento admin->configuration->developer->debug
then you can see which block is rendering the product review
then you can move the block by

```
<move element="Your_block_name" destination="where_to_move" />
```

dont edit core files ,copy files from vendor->magento->magento catalog to
app\design\frontend\your_namespace\your_theme\Magento_Catalog
then do the changes in respective files,
after change 
flush,clean cache, reindex and deploy static content